# REST API and User Authorizations

Tags: angularjs, rest, session, playframework

I have a set of REST API's served using Play Framework. I will now be building a UI layer using Angular JS. It is a portal application where users could log in. I have two questions now:

1. How should the Angular JS app authorize itself against the REST API? Should I authorize for each and every request or could I have some firewall rules that allows access only from the machine that runs the Angular JS app?
2. How do I manage session state? Play application server is purely stateless and I want to keep the session state away from the REST API's. So this leaves me with leaving the session state with the Angular JS App. Is this advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your auth header, you can user interceptors. Below is a generic code and can be made even better:

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function ($q, $injector, cookie, $location, models) {
return {
    request: function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        // if this request is not to authenticate or logout, then refresh the existing token (if possible)
        if (config.url.indexOf("authenticate") < 0 && config.url.indexOf("logout") < 0 && config.url.indexOf("login") < 0) {
            var $http = $injector.get('$http');
            $http.post(Config.api + '/authenticate/refresh').success(function (data) { }).error(function (data) { $location.path("/login"); });
        }
        else
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + cookie.getObject(constant.ckAuth).token;
        return config || $q.when(config)
    },
    response: function (response) { return response || $q.when(response); },
    responseError: function (response) { return $q.reject(response); }
    };
});
```

You can use JWT for auth and store it in `$rootscope`/`$scope` and if you can use `$cookies`. When trying to store data in any of the client objects, you need to understand that it will be visible in the browser (console) itself. So handle the intelligence in the API's end and try using Session State.

#### C# Reference

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Auth"]
```

#### Python Reference

```
import requests 
s = requests.Session() -- Python Reference
```

Comment: I mentioned very clearly in my post above that I use Play framework and it does not have the concept of having a session state.

Comment: Was just a recommendation, You do have sessions in play framework and its how you design your api to manage the auth ( https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaSessionFlash#how-it-is-different-in-play ) . this means it passes session in every HTTP Request headers.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, you need authorization header in every request
2. what exactly do you need to keep? yes, it's totally ok using some service/factory to store important data, that will be used throughout the application